# PHP: Hashtable optimization

Tags: php, performance, hashtable

I have two static hashtables in my program:

```
public static $labels = [
    'id' => 'ID',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'email' => 'E-mail',
    'password' => 'Password',
];

public static $columnTypes = [
    'id' => 'number',
    'name' => 'text',
    'email' => 'text',
    'password' => 'text',
];
```

First is for the labels of the database columns and the second for each type (necessary for filtering).

My problem is that I often need to get the type of a column by its label what leads to speed issues (hashtables are pretty slow in this direction right?).

My approaches would be the following:

1. Type a hashtable `label => type` which is bad because I have to repeat myself and there is no support for other languages
2. Create the `label => type` hashtable in a static content on runtime (is this possible in php?)

Are there better approaches or best practices for this issue and is the second approach possible in php? (maybe with a small example ;)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) ?

Comment: I know how to do the flip, but how can I do it in a static content?

Comment: *"hashtables are pretty slow in this direction right?"* -- wrong. And, anyway, the only data structure you have in PHP is named "[array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)" but in fact it is a hashtable (aka dictionary, aka association map).

Comment: Thank you. I thought to get a key of a value you have to iterate over the whole hashtable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `array_flip` in the class constructor. To avoid repeating it, check whether the flipped array is already set.

```
class YourClass {
    public static $labels = [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'email' => 'E-mail',
        'password' => 'Password',
    ];
    public static $labels_flipped = null;

    public function __construct() {
        if (!$labels_flipped) {
            $labels_flipped = array_flip($labels);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the key having the value then you can use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) or [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

If you need to do this kind of lookup in a **large** array a **big** number of times then it's recommended to flip the keys and values (using [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)) then use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [access the value using `[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

In order to get a real improvement, **large** and **big** in the paragraph above should be counted in thousands. Otherwise, concentrate on optimizations where there really is something to optimize: database, disk access, remote APIs etc.